# IIS 7.5 - Files with no extensions causing Error 404.17

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am currently developping an ASP.NET MVC4 Website and I am trying to include javascript timezone support for `JQuery Flot` with `date.js`.

The timezones informations of date.js are stored into text files with no extensions (ex: tz/northamerica).

When using the Visual Studio Development Server, I can GET any of my timezone files with no problems, but once it's hosted using IIS, I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
>
> The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by
>   the static file handler.
>
> Most likely cause:
>
> The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the
>   static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the
>   request will map to a different handler.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit
>   MIME map.

The rest of my website works perfectly, only those extension less files are causing hiccups.

I am very unfamiliar with IIS configuration, what exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was a problem with IIS 7.5 that [you can patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646735).

Comment: Good find! Although it doesn't seem to be working. I can see the Hotfix as been applied correctl and an emptry string Mime Type has been added to my site.
However, I am still getting the same error, I will continue investigating

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/720043/iis-8-5-serve-file-with-no-extension-from-particular-folder

As per the above, if you include the following within your web.config it'll allow you to serve static extensionless files.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```